# How to add a dm-cache to an already existing luks setup?

Tags: fedora, lvm

I've got two physical devices, a fast SSD and a large HDD. The SSD is in VG `ssd` and ends up serving as mountpoint `/`, the HDD is in VG `dump` and serves as mountpoint `/home`. Both go through LUKS for encryption, both are formatted as ext4.
I could easily spare 40gb on the SSD to serve as a cache for the HDD and I'm wondering if I can change my LV-setup without reformatting.

Is it possible to reduce the size of the root filesystem, then reduce the size of the LV, add two new LVs for cache and metadata and attach the newly created cache-pool to serve the HDD? Remind me on how to setup in such a way, that unencrypted data does not leak to the cache...

Comment: Were you able to address your issue? Did you utilize anything in the answer below or did you take another approach?

Comment: I now used a mixture of the information below to reduce the size of the SSD's filesystem, it's LUKS-container, it's LVM-device and it's partition, create a new encrypted LVM-cache device on it and add it to the HDD's volume group, effectively caching the HDD to the SSD without losing encryption. I will add a answer with all the necessary steps to my own question once I extracted them from my .bash_history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now distilled enough information to answer my own question. Here are my steps for other people to follow.

Usual disclaimer: Modifying existing filesystems and their underlying devices may cause corruption and loss of a data. Plan ahead, backup your data :-)

If you follow these steps, parts of the filesystem layout I started with may not be applicable to your setup, adapt accordingly:

- I'm using Fedora 21.
- The SSD is on `/dev/sda`, provides /boot (`sda1`), swap (`sda2`) and a LUKS-container that hosts LVM-volume `root` in volume-group `ssd` for `ext4`-formatted `/` (`/dev/sda3` -> `/dev/mapper/luks-...` -> `/dev/mapper/ssd-root` -> `/`).
- The HDD is on `/dev/sdb` and provides a LUKS-container that hosts a LVM-volume `dump` in volume-group `dump` for `/home` (`/dev/sdb1` -> `/dev/mapper/luks-...` -> `/dev/mapper/dump-dump` -> `/home`).
- I will resize the `/`-filesystem to make room for about 7.5gb of encrypted(!) cache to serve `/home`.
- Note that LVM, LUKS, the partition table and the filesystems use different block sizes (e.g. my LVM-volumes contain extents of 4mb each, my ext4-filesystems, LUKS, and the partitions are blocks/sectors of 512 bytes each). Chose your sizes so that the alignments match.
- Double-check all numbers you enter manually for consistency. Triple-check that you don't end up with a filesystem that is larger than the logical volume, a logical volume that is larger than the physical volume, a physical volume that is larger than the LUKS-container or a LUKS-container that is larger than the partition.

---

1. Use `lsblk` to remind yourself about your own setup again. Reboot to a LiveCD and open a new terminal session. Switch to root if you want to avoid all the calls to `sudo`...
2. We will need the Fedora-usual names of the LUKS-containers several times. Put them in variables first

   > ```
   > SDA3UUID=luks-`sudo cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda3`
   > SDB1UUID=luks-`sudo cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sdb1`
   > ```

   `$SDA3UUID` now holds the UUID for the `/`-device, `$SDB1UUID` is `/home`.

   Open the `/`-device using LUKS. LVM will discover the volume inside the container and make it available (as `/dev/mapper/ssd-root` in my case).

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 $SDA3UUID
   > ```
3. Reduce the filesystems's size.

   `resize2fs` enforces a filesystem-check first. I will resize the filesystem for `/` to 20 gigabytes.

   > ```
   > sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/ssd-root
   > sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/ssd-root 20g
   > ```

   This process is going to take a while. Note the output "the filesystem is now XYZ blocks long" and the size of each block (5242880 blocks of 4k each in my case).
4. Deactivate and reduce the size of the logical volume that backs the filesystem.

   The `-L`-parameter is given in megabytes by default.

   > ```
   > sudo lvchange -an /dev/mapper/ssd-root
   > sudo lvreduce -L 20480 /dev/mapper/ssd-root
   > ```
5. Reduce the size of the physical volume that backs the logical volume.

   Note that there is some overhead for LUKS and LVM, so the physical volume should remain a little larger than the logical volume. I added two extents.

   > ```
   > sudo pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 20488 /dev/mapper/$SDA3UUID
   > ```
6. Reduce the size of the LUKS-container.

   The `-b`-parameter is given in blocks. Use `pvdisplay` and calculate as *total numbers of physical extents * size of extent * 1024**2 / 512* (e.g. `python -c "print 5121*4*1024**2/512"`)

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup resize -b 41951232 $SDA3UUID
   > ```

   Use `sudo cryptsetup status $SDA3UUID` to find out about the container's new size. In my case, the container is 2mb *larger* than the physical volume and filesystem it contains (there goes your alignment).
7. Reduce the size of the partition and create a new partition for the cache.

   Deactivate the logical volume and the container first.

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup luksClose $SDA3UUID
   > sudo fdisk /dev/sda
   > ```

   Delete the partition that used to be be `sda3`. Create a new partition that starts on the same sector as the old one (!) and which is "+XYZ" in size ("+41951232" in my case). Also create a new partition that fills the device (7.5gb in my case). Write the partition table to disk and exit `fdisk`.

   Check that the filesystem is still alive:

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 $SDA3UUID
   > ```

   `lvs` should show the logical volume.

   > ```
   > sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/ssd-root
   > ```
8. Create a new LUKS-container on the new partition to host the encrypted cache.

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda4
   > SDA4UUID=luks-`sudo cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda4`
   > ```
9. Open the HDD's LUKS-container and extend the volume group that ends up hosting `/home` with the new device.

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdb1 $SDB1UUID
   > ```

   `lvs` should show the volume group `dump` being active now.

   > ```
   > sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda4 $SDA4UUID
   > sudo vgextend dump /dev/mapper/$SDA4UUID
   > ```
10. Create a logical volume for the the cache's metadata and the cache itself.

    It is said that the metadata-volume should be 0.1% the size of the cache itself but 8mb at minimum. Notice again that there is some overhead, so I chose the size of the cache to be 99% of the physical volume's remaining size.

    > ```
    > sudo lvcreate -L 20M -n lv_cache_meta dump /dev/mapper/$SDA4UUID
    > sudo lvcreate -l 99%FREE -n lv_cache dump /dev/mapper/$SDA4UUID
    > sudo lvconvert --type cache-pool --poolmetadata dump/lv_cache_meta dump/lv_cache
    > ```
11. Add the cache to the logical volume that hosts `/home`.

    > ```
    > sudo lvconvert --type cache --cachepool dump/lv_cache dump/dump
    > ```

    The output should be something to the sound of "Logical volume dump/dump is now cached."
12. Update `crypttab` so the new LUKS-container is opened during boot.

    > ```
    > mkdir root
    > sudo mount /dev/mapper/ssd-root root
    > sudo su
    > UUID=`cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda4`
    > echo "luks-$UUID UUID=$UUID none" >> root/etc/crypttab
    > exit
    > sudo umount root
    > ```
13. Cross your fingers and reboot into your original system.

    After reboot you can get some statistics about the cache like so:

    > ```
    > lvs --rows -o +devices,cache_total_blocks,cache_used_blocks,cache_dirty_blocks,cache_read_hits,cache_read_misses,cache_write_hits,cache_write_misses dump
    > ```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `lvmcache(7)` which utilizes `dm-cache`. Nice writeup here on doing so:

https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/using-lvms-new-cache-feature/

This, according to the author, requires the use of a single volume group. Thus you'll need to merge your volume groups. See following link which uses vgmerge(8) to do so:

https://sites.google.com/site/rhelworldexperience/home/rhel-disk-management---tips-and-tricks/mergingvolumegroupsinrhel-vgmerge

If you have `LVM` on top of `LUKS`, I believe the caching will be unencrypted based on the explanation of the device manager found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto. `LUKS` on top of `LVM` I believe will cache encrypted data.

Here is a good reference for resizing when `LVM` is on top of `LUKS`: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions. One should be able to adapt this for the other way around.

Note that it is probably best to setup a test system to verify the process on and/or do a full back with a tested/verified restore process in place.